# How to plot a Gaussian cube file with python/matplotlib?

Tags: python, gaussian, visualization-software

I know there are programs that can automatically visualize .cube files (like VMD), but I'm trying to do it myself in python/matplotlib (or equivalent) to better understand what the numbers mean.

I understand that there are nx*ny*nz grid points in the file (and can be saved in an array fo dimensions [nx,ny,nz]), but I can't quite figure out how to visualize them or what kind of plot they correspond to (with respect to the modules available on matplotlib).

Part of a script that extracts info from cube file :

```py
filename1 = 'density.cube'
with open(filename1, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
no_of_atoms, _, _, _ = lines[2].split()
no_of_atoms = int(no_of_atoms)
xdim, _, _, _ = lines[3].split()
xdim = int(xdim)
ydim, _, _, _ = lines[4].split()
ydim = int(ydim)
zdim, _, _, _ = lines[5].split()
zdim = int(zdim)

elements = [None] * no_of_atoms
atoms_x_coords_in_density = [None] * no_of_atoms
atoms_y_coords_in_density = [None] * no_of_atoms
atoms_z_coords_in_density = [None] * no_of_atoms

for _ in range(no_of_atoms):
    (elements[_], __,
     atoms_x_coords_in_density[_],
     atoms_y_coords_in_density[_],
     atoms_z_coords_in_density[_]) = lines[6 + _].split()
    elements[_] = int(elements[_])
    atoms_x_coords_in_density[_] = float(atoms_x_coords_in_density[_])
    atoms_y_coords_in_density[_] = float(atoms_y_coords_in_density[_])
    atoms_z_coords_in_density[_] = float(atoms_z_coords_in_density[_])

# Load the data, we need to remove the first 8 lines and the space after
str = ' '.join(file(filename1).readlines()[(6 + no_of_atoms):])
data = np.fromstring(str, sep=' ')
data.shape = (xdim, ydim, zdim)
```

So, the grid points are in the `data` array, but I'm not sure how to plot them. I've seen an example using the `mayavi` package, but that's also a black box solution (plus I couldn't get it installed for some reason -- the conda version seems broken). I'm trying to understand about what's happening under the hood.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The data is electron density on a discretized volume. Each data point is the value of the electron density inside a cube of size dx*dy*dz. The position of this cube is encoded in the arrangement of the data points. I.e. you can map the linear index of each data point to a point in 3 dimensional space. Three dimensional densities are often plotted as volume plots or as iso-surface plots. But 3D plots of this kind are not the strong suite of matplotlib and I wouldn't expect particularly good results, especially not straight out-of-the-box.

Comment: I think the plotly package can do isosurface plots. I don't quite understand what you mean by: "The position of this cube is encoded in the arrangement of the data points. I.e. you can map the linear index of each data point to a point in 3 dimensional space." Could you elaborate? Or point me to a suitable reference?

Comment: A good explanation of the cube format is given here, http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/cube/, I hope that link makes it clear what I meant. The Gaussian website also provides a description, https://gaussian.com/cubegen/. I do not clearly understand what your question is. Is all that you need a clear explanation of the cube format so that you can parse it ? Or do you not understand what kind of physical property the cube file represents ?

Comment: Mostly the first. I understand physically what it is, but I guess I don't have enough experience in geometry/visualization to know how to plot it. Like, what exactly in the cube file determines the "shape" of the density in 3d surface? For example, the Plotly module has functions for [isosurface](https://plotly.com/python/3d-isosurface-plots/) and [volumetric](https://plotly.com/python/3d-volume-plots/) plots, but I can't figure out how to parse the data within a cube file to convert them to arguments for either of those functions (assuming they're right for this type of visualization)

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future !!!

Comment: @HansWurst I might try to add an answer here when I find the time, but from the comments it looks like you already have most of whats needed for an answer, so I'll give you the first crack at it if you want it. It would also essentially address this [prior question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6237/how-to-plot-a-charge-density-from-a-chgcar-file-in-python), so it seems like an explicit answer could be useful to a decent number of users.

Comment: @Tyberius Thank you for your consideration. I'm quite busy myself currently and don't intend to write an answer so please feel free to write one. Anyone should feel free to do so, my comments are never meant to "block" other people from answering or as "reservation" for myself.

Comment: @Tyberius I was able to figure it out. The plotly "volume plot" function essentially does it: https://plotly.com/python/3d-volume-plots/ .When I have the time I'll try to write up an answer.

Comment: Perfect! I figured it wasn't anything too difficult, but I didn't want to discourage other users by answering. Getting rep is a lot trickier than it was when the site started, so I want other users to get those chances when they are available.

Comment: The closure of this question is really just for bookkeeping to separate it from the truly unaswered questions. Once you are ready to self-answer, I can reopen this post.

Comment: Was the question about a specific function to plot the data (e.g. plotly's volume plot trace) or more of a general question on how one must process the grid of values to get to a visualization (a "rawer" approach, let's say)? If it's the second one I can answer, since it was hard for me to find the answer and maybe someone finds it useful :)

Answer (score 5):

The Python package [mayavi](https://pypi.org/project/mayavi/) uses [VTK](https://vtk.org/) for 3D visualization and offers thus several poptions for plotting volumetric data. [ase](https://pypi.org/project/ase/) has an interface to mayavi and facilitates IO of electronic structure grid formats such as cube files.

```
python3 -m ase.visualize.mlab file.cube
```

will visualize the grid data from `file.cube`. To plot from within your own python code, use the method [ase.visualize.mlab.plot](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/_modules/ase/visualize/mlab.html#plot), which takes an ase atoms object, the grid data, and a list of floats to plot iso-surfaces at as parameters.

Comment: Executing this errors for me with an error at `ase/calculators/calculator.py:191`: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'`. (Running on Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: Actually, nvm. My file was named `file.cub` instead of `file.cube` and thus a different path within the program was taken. Renaming the file to have the proper file extension fixes above error.